# Tricking numpy/python into representing very large and very small numbers

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, numbers, scipy

I need to compute the integral of the following function within ranges that start as low as `-150`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import ndtr

def my_func(x):
    return np.exp(x ** 2) * 2 * ndtr(x * np.sqrt(2))
```

The problem is that this part of the function

```
np.exp(x ** 2)
```

tends toward infinity -- I get `inf` for values of `x` less than approximately `-26`.

And this part of the function

```
2 * ndtr(x * np.sqrt(2))
```

which is equivalent to

```
from scipy.special import erf

1 + erf(x)
```

tends toward 0.

So, a very, very large number times a very, very small number should give me a reasonably sized number -- but, instead of that, `python` is giving me `nan`.

What can I do to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Are you sure there are no analytical solutions to your integral?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque no, i'm not.  do you know where i might find one?  i certainly don't have the math chops to figure it out on my own.

Comment: mathstackexchange maybe - or wolframalpha - or sympy

Comment: Does something like this help? `np.exp(x**2 + np.log(2) + np.log(ndtr(x*np.sqrt(2))))`

Comment: @askewchan sort of.  the `nan` values are replaced with zeros.  where there was a drop from `0.02` to `nan`, now it's `0.02` to `0`.  what it should be is a very gradual descent from `0.02` closer and closer to `0`.

Comment: Does that substantially affect the value of the integral? Alternatively, you may be able to figure out analytically what `log(ndtr(x))` is, and break it up like for the `exp` term.. you get the idea.

Comment: @askewchan ah, good idea.  it does substantially affect the integral -- because i'm integrating in some cases entirely within the `0` zone.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque wolframalpha gives me something involving the "generalized hypergeometric function." is that implementable in python?  i would need `hyp2f2`, but it looks as though `scipy` doesn't have that.  but, now i see that `mpmath` does . . . whatever that is.

Comment: You could eliminate the `log` call in @askewchan's solution by using [`scipy.special.log_ndtr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.log_ndtr.html)

Comment: @ali_m, lovely :)  `x=np.arange(-100,10,25); np.exp(x**2 + np.log(2) + log_ndtr(x*np.sqrt(2))) --> [0.00564161,  0.00752186,  0.01128154,  0.02254957,  1. ]`

Comment: It probably is, but if Ali_m solution is correct, I suggest you use that instead. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There already is such a function: [`erfcx`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfcx.html). I think `erfcx(-x)` should give you the integrand you want (note that `1+erf(x)=erfc(-x)`).

Comment: `erf(x)` is an odd function: `erf(-x) = -erf(x)`.  So `erfc(-x) = 1 - erf(-x) = 1 + erf(x)` (the first equality is the definition of `erfc`, the second uses the odd symmetry).

Comment: Note that by flipping the signs of the arguments, you can replace, for example,  `quad(my_func, -14, -4)` with `quad(erfcx, 4, 14)`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks.  one last question: `erfcx` is defined as `exp(x ** 2) * erfc(x)`.  if i do `erfcx(-x)`, doesn't that give me `exp(-x ** 2) * erfc(-x)`, when what i want is `exp(x ** 2) * erfc(-x)`?  or, wait, i guess it gives me `exp((-x) ** 2) * erf((-x))`, which *is* what i want.

Answer (score 5):

I think a combination of @askewchan's solution and [`scipy.special.log_ndtr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.log_ndtr.html) will do the trick:

```
from scipy.special import log_ndtr

_log2 = np.log(2)
_sqrt2 = np.sqrt(2)

def my_func(x):
    return np.exp(x ** 2) * 2 * ndtr(x * np.sqrt(2))

def my_func2(x):
    return np.exp(x * x + _log2 + log_ndtr(x * _sqrt2))

print(my_func(-150))
# nan

print(my_func2(-150)
# 0.0037611803122451198
```

For `x <= -20`, `log_ndtr(x)` [uses a Taylor series expansion of the error function to iteratively compute the log CDF directly](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/07c263874ca93312d9a54c1249ff3a7b9a88226e/scipy/special/cephes/ndtr.c#L296-L338), which is much more numerically stable than simply taking `log(ndtr(x))`.

---

## Update

As you mentioned in the comments, the `exp` can also overflow if `x` is sufficiently large. Whilst you could work around this using `mpmath.exp`, a simpler and faster method is to cast up to a `np.longdouble` which, on my machine, can represent values up to 1.189731495357231765e+4932:

```
import mpmath

def my_func3(x):
    return mpmath.exp(x * x + _log2 + log_ndtr(x * _sqrt2))

def my_func4(x):
    return np.exp(np.float128(x * x + _log2 + log_ndtr(x * _sqrt2)))

print(my_func2(50))
# inf

print(my_func3(50))
# mpf('1.0895188633566085e+1086')

print(my_func4(50))
# 1.0895188633566084842e+1086

%timeit my_func3(50)
# The slowest run took 8.01 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that
# an intermediate result is being cached  100000 loops, best of 3: 15.5 µs per
# loop

%timeit my_func4(50)
# The slowest run took 11.11 times longer than the fastest. This could mean
# that an intermediate result is being cached  100000 loops, best of 3: 2.9 µs
# per loop
```

Comment: Probably a minor note for this use case, but for scalars, `math.log` and `math.sqrt` are about ten times faster than `np.log` and `np.sqrt`. Or even faster, `log2 = math.log(2)` outside of the function definition. For me this gives about a factor of two speedup for the call to `quad`

Comment: @askewchan good point - I wasn't really thinking about performance

Comment: this is great.  many thanks.  i'm testing it now.  `my_func2(50)` raises a `RunTimeWarning`: "overflow encountered in exp."  it appears that `np.exp` can't handle inputs larger than `709`.  (same for `math.exp`.)  any idea how i can get around that?

Comment: i'm going to look into an analytical solution to the integral, because it seems that the overflow is a dead end.

Comment: @SalvadorDali i'm not sure what you're asking.  all i did was `my_func2(50)`.  i didn't calculate `integral(log(my_func2(50)))` or intend to calculate that.  i guess my assumption was that `quad` wouldn't work if the function itself couldn't be evaluated at that point.  i think i tried `quad` first, and it failed.  (or was your question for @ali_m?)

Comment: @ali_m using `mpmath.exp` instead of `np.exp` when `x` is large resolves all my problems.  you might want to update your answer with that information.  (or i can do it if you aren't sure what i mean.)  many thanks!

Comment: See @SimonByrne's answer for a very simple approach.

Comment: @dbliss you should accept Simon's answer instead of mine

Comment: @SalvadorDali Was your comment directed at me? Mine and askewchan's  solution also computes `f(x)` rather than `log(f(x))` - it just uses the fact that `a exp(b) = exp(a + log(b))` to avoid overflow inside the exponent. It's a moot point anyway, since Simon's answer is much better.

Comment: @ali_m my comment was related to you. Now I see that I was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @ali_m i've accepted simon's answer, but i still think yours is a valuable contribution to this thread.  it greatly enhanced my thinking about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how helpful will this be, but here are a couple of thoughts that are too long for a comment.

You need to calculate the integral of [image: 2 \cdot e^{x^2} \cdot f(\sqrt{2}x)], which you [correctly identified](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ndtr.html#scipy.special.ndtr) would be [image: e^{x^2}*(1 + erf(x))]. Opening the brackets you can integrate both parts of the summation.

[image]

Scipy has this [imaginary error function implemented](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfi.html#scipy.special.erfi)

The second part is harder:

[image]

This is a [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function). Sadly it looks like scipy [does not have an implementation of it](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html#hypergeometric-functions), but [this package](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) claims it does.

Here I used indefinite integrals without constants, knowing the `from` `to` values it is clear how to use definite ones.

Comment: what seems to be screwing me up with this strategy is that `scipy.special.erfi(50)` evaluates to `inf`.

Comment: math question for ya: how would i handle the case where my integral is "half definite" -- i.e., i have an upper limit, but my lower limit is `-inf`.  i'm not sure how to evaluate the functions in your question *at* `-inf`.

Comment: @dbliss `scipy.special.erfi(50)` is inf. If `b = super huge`, then most probably `b + a` is also super huge, where a > 0 (because the second integral is also positive if x > 1). Not really sure how do you want to calculate it.

Comment: (1) right, but `mpmath.erfi(50)` returns `6 * 10 ** 1083`.  given what i end up doing with the integral, it's nice to have an exact representation here.  (2) what i need to do is evaluate the integral we've been talking about from `-inf` to `x`, where `x` varies from function call to function call from `-150` to `50`.  i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: ^ never mind.  my two most recent comments are really a separate question having to do with the computation of a double integral.  i'm going to try to work this out on my own, and, if i can't, post a new question.